# Websockets behind enterprises proxies

Tags: proxy, websocket

According to [these](http://www.ietf.org/mail-archive/web/hybi/current/msg01605.html) [articles](http://blog.caplin.com/2010/04/13/html5-websocket-failure-rates/), Websocket success rate is only 63 % (if you have a websocket-ready browser).

And this InfoQ article (http://www.infoq.com/articles/Web-Sockets-Proxy-Servers) says that you have better chance to connect by using Secured Websockets (wss://).

Does anyone have any feedback on their use of the Websockets for an enterprise ready application, behind enterprise proxies and firewall ?

I'm sorry if my question is off-topic.

Regards,
Nico

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That email and article are approaching two years old.

Those problems were either server or proxy related. The reason that wss:// is more successful is because SSL traffic is more opaque to intermediaries and so it is more likely that it will just be passed along without interference.

As WebSockets becomes more common, those issues will begin to dissipate as the issues are fixed in proxies, firewalls, load-balancers, and web servers.

Also, regarding WebSockets support in browsers, if you include the Flash based [web-socket-js](https://github.com/gimite/web-socket-js) as a polyfill/fallback in your web application then you get nearly universal browser support.

Comment: Thanks for the pointers, and for the JS script ! But do you have any feedback in the actual Websocket success rate ?

Comment: @nico_ekito, I am the creator of noVNC (HTML5 VNC client) which uses WebSockets for transporting the RFB/VNC protocol. It's used by quite a few projects and companies. There have been problem reports at many levels but I don't recall any related to the problems in that article and email (e.g. intermediaries). It's anecdotal evidence. I myself would be interested in a more up to date study on the issue.

Comment: I have a few projects where I'll have to use the Websockets. I'll update this post with my personnal feedback. Thanks.

Comment: @nico_ekito I am interested in your study. Wondering what is your personal feedback.

Comment: @nico_ekito would you like to share your personal feedback over this?
I am trying to use AWS IoT MQTT over WSS and it fails behind several corporate networks, while simple https rest api calls don't. any ideas will be greatly appreciated.