# Noode.js ws: Server doesn't know that the client is disconnected

Tags: node.js, websocket, ping

We have a problem in our project using the node [ws websockets library](https://github.com/websockets/ws).
When the client looses network connection the only way to know that the client is disconnected is by sending a ws.ping() from the server. This is too resource consuming for us.

Does anybody know if there is a default way to get the ws server to use TCP level keepalives instead of using the ping/pong functionality?

Comment: If you use socket.io on top of webSocket, the client will do a regular ping to the server.  The client uses it to know when the connection died so it can do a reconnect.  But, if the server knows that any "live" client will send a ping every X time interval, then the server can use the fact that it has not received such a ping in that X time interval to tear down a dead connection itself.  Or, if you control the client, you can just configure your own ping interval even without socket.io.

Comment: Thanks for the comment jfriend00. I have implemented a ping/pong functionality already but was looking for a solution for this that doesn't involve the application layer but rather just using the network layer. Found an answer here why TCP keep alives is not a good idea for websockets:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23238319/websockets-ping-pong-why-not-tcp-keepalive

The socket.io library is not usable for us since after v1.0 the lib doesn't seem to support the cluster module. That made me choose ws websockets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this by letting the client send a response when a message is received.