# Serverless web socket server?

Tags: amazon-web-services, azure, websocket

Are there any serverless technologies that allow a serverless websocket server to be built?

I know the nature of long running connections is that they are stateful, but if the only state is the connection itself at the transport layer then it seems like there could be a serverless product that abstracts this away so you only deal with the application layer. Is there a cloud provider (AWS, Azure, etc) that allows this? I can't see a way for AWS Lambda or Azure Functions to achieve this.

Anyone got any ideas? Just checking.

Thanks

Answer (score 7):

With the release of WebSocket support for AWS API Gateway, you can create a server-less WebSocket API.

A WebSocket API is composed of one or more routes. To determine which route a particular inbound request should use, you provide a route selection expression. The expression is evaluated against an inbound request to produce a value that corresponds to one of your route’s routeKey values. API gateway routes the request to corresponding lambda function.

From AWS blog [example](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/announcing-websocket-apis-in-amazon-api-gateway/), 
[image]

The application is composed of the WebSocket API in API Gateway that handles the connectivity between the client and servers (1). Two AWS Lambda functions react when clients connect (2) or disconnect (5) from the API. The sendMessage function (3) is invoked when the clients send messages to the server. The server sends the message to all connected clients (4) using the new API Gateway Management API. To track each of the connected clients, use a DynamoDB table to persist the connection identifiers (You can also use it to store other state information about the connection).

You can extend this to send messages to clients on any changes to data using [DynamoDB Streams](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Streams.html)

Answer (score 1):

Currently AWS Lambda and Azure Functions doesn't support this. If you plan to setup an scalable environment in AWS with websockets, you can use [Application Load Balancer](https://aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/applicationloadbalancer/) and in front of ECS cluster or EC2 instances with Websocket supported server like NodeJS.

Another solution is to go with fully managed services, like [Google Firebase Service](https://firebase.google.com) or [Pubnub](https://www.pubnub.com/) in your architecture to handle the real-time part.

Comment: Thanks @ashan. I did not know about the fully managed ones

Answer (score 1):

*if the only state is the connection itself at the transport layer*

That's not really the case.  Web socket connections [exchange keep-alives](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23238319/1695906) as layer 7 payload.  Others might argue that it's more accurately described as a sublayer somewhere between layers 6 and 7... but in any event, it is well-above the transport layer.

And many applications use web sockets in other ways that are also not stateless.  Once connected, then authenticated, there's no need to continually re-authenticate, because the client on the socket now will be the same client 15 minutes from now, and this is overhead that would not be avoidable in a serverless environment -- every action on a websocket would need to be re-authenticated.  For another example, with a constant data stream, the server might keep track of what has been sent or what specific subset of the stream the client is interested in.

If you aren't maintaining (or don't need) a persistent connection to a server, the question could be asked "why are you using a web socket?"

Perhaps also relevant: HAProxy, a commonly used load balancer with web socket support, maintains a persistent connection to a single back-end server for each current web socket connection.  If that backend server goes offline, there's no provision in the balancer to choose another back-end for the existing connection.  The client will need to reconnect.

Answer (score 1):

AWS IoT provides MQTT endpoints and it supports MQTT + WebSocket on port 443. This might be the closest thing you can get as a hosted service on AWS.
Check this link:   [AWS IoT Protocols](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/protocols.html) 
You can define rules that trigger Lambdas on AWS IoT or pass them to Kinesis and process streams through Lambdas.

Answer (score 1):

[Fanout](https://fanout.io/) can do this. It works as a proxy that can translate WebSocket client activity into a series of HTTP requests. This allows FaaS backends like Lambda to manage raw WebSockets. The function is invoked only when there is activity to react to.

Docs: https://fanout.io/docs/devguide.html#custom-websocket-api

WebSocket-over-HTTP protocol: http://pushpin.org/docs/protocols/websocket-over-http/

Python helper library: https://github.com/fanout/python-faas-grip

Answer (score 0):

AWS Lambda/Azure Functions/GCP Functions don't support web-socket protocol. So it's normal to use third-party services for this purpose.
In additional to comments above I can propose Ably: https://www.ably.io/ .
It provides api/libraries to handle web-socket without pain.