# NodeJS with Einaros WebSocket : Client Ping Server VS Server Ping Client

Tags: node.js, websocket

I am developing a WebSocket service using NodeJS and Einaros WS module and I have raised this question: [NodeJS Einaros WS Connection Timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25352111/nodejs-einaros-ws-connection-timeout) which apparently no one know the answer so I presume I should write my own ping pong based system to check whether a client is still connected or not.

I am not sure whether I should write code on server side or client side; I mean if the server should ping the client or... the client (which is my own websocket application) should ping the server.

Is there any difference between both methods ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is called a heartbeat and is usually sent by the client every 5 seconds with a ping frame (`0x09`) as opcode while the server responds with a pong frame (`0xA`) as opcode.

In theory it doesn't really matter whether it's the server or client initiating the heartbeat, but in a real-world situation it is usually better that the client keep itself updated whether the server is there or not to be able to inform the user as quickly as possible.