# Node JS - How Can You Tell If A Socket Is Already Open With The Einaros WS Socket Module?

Tags: javascript, node.js, events, asynchronous, websocket

I'm currently using einaros' NodeJS WS module to create a websocket client.
When initializing the socket client, I use the 'open' event to determine when the connection is open, but once it's open, how would I be able to check if it's still open?

Is there a property on the 'WebSocket' object that I can use to quickly check the status of the socket?

Is - *websocketInstance.readyState* - adequate?

Comment: `if (socket.readyState === 1)` then the system thinks the socket is still open.  The only better assurance you can get is to send a message and await the response.

Comment: You can also monitor the onclose event if you want to know exactly when the readyState changes to closed.

Comment: @jfriend00 sometimes the `onclose` [is never fired](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25352111/nodejs-einaros-ws-connection-timeout)

Comment: @TheSexiestManinJamaica - Read the last paragraph in my answer below.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`socket.readyState` will tell you what the socket thinks its state is.  There is no other, more accurate property that you can consult than `socket.readyState`.

If what you want to know is when the socket has finished connecting and is now considered open, then you can register an event handler for the `open` event.  This will tell you when it has finished connecting.

If you want a real-time notification when the socket closes or experiences an error, you can use an event listener for the `error` or `close` events.  The `close` event just means that socket is closing and the `socket.readyState` value is now changing to closed.

A more guaranteed to be up-to-date method of checking the socket is to first check `socket.readyState` and, if that says the socket is open, then you can send a test packet to the other end and only when you get a response back from the test packet will you truly know that socket is operational.

The `socket.io` library (built on top of webSockets) does exactly this, sending regular keep-alive packets and listening for responses.  If it goes some period of time with no response, then it will close the existing socket and attempt to re-establish a new connection (figuring the prior connection was lost somehow).  In this way, the `socket.io` library can even survive a server reboot or a temporary drop in client internet connectivity as it will see that the connection was lost and then transparently re-establish a new connection in its place.

Comment: This is a little too abstract for me. I'd appreciate it if you could show me some actual nodejs code. So suppose I want to see if there is a listener on localhost at port 5858. How would I write a function that returns true if one is there and false if not? Thanks.

Comment: @rocky - that's a different question than what was asked here.  I'd suggest you start a new question of your own that asks about your specific situation.  You can link the new question here in a comment and I'll take a look after you post it.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should watch for the error and disconnect callbacks. That way you'll get notified when it closes.