# In nodejs, how do I check if a port is listening or in use

Tags: node.js, sockets

I'll be very specific here in the hope that folks who understand this can edit to rephrase to the general situation.

Currently when you run "node debug", it spawns a process to listen on port 5858. Then in the parent, a connection is attempted to that port.

However if you have another "node debug" session running, currently "node debug" hangs because that port is in use.

Specifically the message you see is:

```
 $ node debug example/gcd.js 3 5
< debugger listening on port 5858 >
connecting...
```

Better would be for it to detect that the port is in use (without a connecting to it which might mess up another client that is trying to connect that existing debugger).

*Edit:* The accepted solution is now in [trepan-ni](https://www.npmjs.com/package/trepan-ni) and [trepanjs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/trepanjs).

See also [Node JS - How Can You Tell If A Socket Is Already Open With The Einaros WS Socket Module?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27256432/node-js-how-can-you-tell-if-a-socket-is-already-open-with-the-einaros-ws-socke/27257626#comment47845396_27257626)

Comment: You can try and listen on the port and see if you get a `EADDRINUSE` error back.

Comment: @robertklep while this is along the right idea, I was looking for specific code.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

A variation on the following is what I used:

```js
var net = require('net');

var portInUse = function(port, callback) {
    var server = net.createServer(function(socket) {
    socket.write('Echo server\r\n');
    socket.pipe(socket);
    });

    server.on('error', function (e) {
    callback(true);
    });
    server.on('listening', function (e) {
    server.close();
    callback(false);
    });

    server.listen(port, '127.0.0.1');
};

portInUse(5858, function(returnValue) {
    console.log(returnValue);
});
```

The actual commit which is a little more involved is https://github.com/rocky/trepanjs/commit/f219410d72aba8cd4e91f31fea92a5a09c1d78f8

Comment: Always returns false for me, net is installed and a port is accessible with telnet. What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 7):

You should be able to use the [`node-netstat` module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-netstat) to detect ports that are being listened to. <strike>Unfortunately, it seems that it only supports Windows and Linux, as is. However, the changes that would be required to have it support OS X do not look to be terribly large.</strike> UPDATE: It now supports OS X...er macOS...er whatever they're calling it now.

Comment: Thanks for the plug. I'm the author for `node-netstat` and just wanted to mention that it has OS X support.

Answer (score 3):

Use inner http module:

```js
const isPortFree = port =>
  new Promise(resolve => {
    const server = require('http')
      .createServer()
      .listen(port, () => {
        server.close()
        resolve(true)
      })
      .on('error', () => {
        resolve(false)
      })
  })
```

Comment: It looks like this creates or tries to create a new something listening on the port, however brief. I wite though: "Better would be for it to detect that the port is in use (without a connecting to it which might mess up another client that is trying to connect that existing debugger).". And that is also tree for another client which is trying to set up a connection to listen on the port.

Answer (score 0):

You can use https://www.npmjs.com/package/systeminformation

Something like:

```js
import systeminformation from "systeminformation";

async function isPortInUse(port) {
    const networkConnections = await systeminformation.networkConnections();

    return networkConnections.find((networkConnection) => {
        return networkConnection.localPort === String(port);
    }) !== undefined;
}
```

You can also check if `networkConnection.state` equals `'LISTEN'` depending on your use case.

I honestly think creating a new server and closing it, like suggested in other answers, just to check if a port is free, is a very bad solution. Not only does it block the port for a brief moment without any real justification, it is also more complex than using systeminformation or netstat, and systeminformation can provide you with many more details about the nature of the port.