# how to close socket server in node-rstp-stream module node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, cordova, express, websocket

I am using **onvif** node js module and **node-rstp-stream** module to convert RSTP stream to img stream which can be used in phonegap(RSTP stream is not supported in phonegap I think).
Here I am using express js, so whenever I send a request to /livestreaming first time it works fine but not next load it tries to create one instance on same port number which creates an issue. Is there way to check if the server is running close on every request and start it again so that we dont the port already in use error. Is there a way better than this please let me know.

Below is the code which I tried.

```
app.get('/livestreaming', function (req, res) {
    if(cam !== null) {
        cam.getStreamUri({protocol:'RTSP'}, function(err, stream) {
             newsocket = new Stream({
                name: 'mysoc',
                streamUrl:stream.uri,
                wsPort: 8888
            });
        });
    } else {
        res.json({"error":"connect to camera"});
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The **node-rtsp-stream** library does not provide any way to check if the port is already in use, neither any way to close the socket server.

So, from my point of view you have two options:

1. Try to connect to your socket server port to use if it is available, for example by doing a ping, and only launch a new Stream in case is not.
2. Since the **node-rtsp-stream** library is very simple, and I already have practice with it, you can add this code right after your newly created stream:

   ```
   newsocket.wsServer.on('error', function() {
       newsocket.mpeg1Muxer.stream.kill();
   });
   ```

So, where this came? If you take a look to the library, you will find that the **wsServer** is your socket server and **mpeg1Muxer** is the stream open with your camera. Because of the already in use error, the server won't launch, but you should also kill the ffmpeg process. This way, if the server is already running, nothing happend, and if not, it will launch.

This last solution is little bit tricky, but I thing it will work.

Hope it helps

Comment: So if this kills the process then how will it start again ? I need to kill and then start again

Comment: Ok, I underestand now. I think the accepted answer to this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29860354/in-nodejs-how-do-i-check-if-a-port-is-listening-or-in-use) will work for you. Using the provided answer, you can check if the port is in use, and only create the Stream object if it is not. Hope it helps

Comment: How to run seperate streams for seperate cameras

Comment: Just create a new Stream object for each camera. Each stream object should have a different port in order to prevent the previous error.

Comment: But that will need different ports for each stream :(