# Cannot call redis.get() function inside websocket ping

Tags: node.js, websocket, redis

I have the following node.js code running well, but I cannot seem to get `console.log` to execute - what could the reason be? The `redis` is in scope and the `redis.get()` works fine in an earlier location (so I know the syntax is fine).. The console.log that does not execute is commented with the line "# cannot execute this line" in the code. Would be grateful for any pointers on how to debug..

The program prints out 'pong' and 'pong2', so I know it is responding to a ping.

```
var WebSocketServer = require('ws').Server
var wss = new WebSocketServer({
    port: 8080
});
var redis = redis_server.createClient(6379, 'localhost');

wss.on('connection', function(ws) {
    ws_auth(redis, ws, function(authresult, uid) {
        if (!authresult) {
            ws.close();
            return;
        }
        ws.on('ping', function() {
            console.log('pong')
            var cookie = ws.upgradeReq.headers.cookie;
            cookie_json = JSON.parse(cookie);
            redis.get('session:' + cookie_json.sessionid, function(err, value) {
                console.log(getDateTime() + ': value ' + value + " session exits");#cannot execute this line
            });
            ws.pong();
            console.log('pong2')
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Is some client sending a `ping` message to your server to trigger that first `console.log()` statement?  You may want to read this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10586583/816620.

Comment: @jfriend00 Thanks - The program prints out 'pong', so I know it is responding to a ping.

Comment: then perhaps you should clarify in your question which `console.log()` you're asking about.

Comment: @jfriend00 I did - the code says "# cannot execute this line" - but I will add this to the question body rather than the code.

Comment: What is `ws_auth()`? It's being passed the `redis` handle, so it may be doing stuff to it that is causing `redis.get()` to fail somehow.

Comment: Add try catch block around the code to see what exception is being thrown. May be that can give you some pointers.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the JSON.parse is throwing an error which is being swallowed. It would be valuable to determine if the reddit server is receiving an event or not.

Comment: Thank for the reply! I updated the code to reflect that is prints pong and pong2 (shows that it is going through the code). cookie_json.sessionid also evaluated properly (I replaced the whole key with 'name' and no difference. I also ran redis in monitor mode, and I see that that the string gets set in redis, but the command from the .js program never reaches the redis server.