# How to send WebSocket PING frame from/to server to/from client

Tags: vert.x

I try to implement client/server ping/pong.

How I know websockets have ping/pong frames.

But in vertx I don't see api for these frames, only text/binary:

```
WebSocket::writeFrame(WebSocketFrame.binaryFrame(...)
```

Should I implement ping with binary/text frame?

Answer (score 0):

If for some reason you still would like to send a PONG frame, you can do it like that:

```
WebSocketFrame f = new WebSocketFrameImpl(FrameType.PONG, someBinaryDataHere);
ws.writeFrame(f);
```

Where `ws` is your WebSocket handler.

As of client, if you mean a JavaScript client, it doesn't support custom PING frames: [Sending websocket ping/pong frame from browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10585355/sending-websocket-ping-pong-frame-from-browser)