# How to implement Ping/Pong request for webSocket connection alive in javascript?

Tags: javascript, web, websocket, ping, pong

I use websocket in javascript. But the connection close after one minute.

I am wondering somethings:

1- Is not Websocket naturaly providing with Ping/Pong messages not to close the connection? I think it have to. Otherwise what is the difference between websocket and TCP connection?

2- If I have to send the ping/pong messages, how is the ping message sent? What am I need to do? Is WebSocket object provide a ping method? Or should I call a method as websocket.send("ping") ? I am use naturaly WebSocket object in javascipt.

3- Should the server respond to Ping requests with Pong? Should this be implemented separately on the server side?

Note:Sorry for my english.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

At this point in time, heartbeats are normally implemented on the server side: there's not much you can do from the client end.

However, if the server keeps killing your socket connection, and you have no control over it, it is possible for the client to send arbitrary data to the websocket on an interval:

```
let socket = null;

function connect_socket() {
  socket = new WebSocket(ws_url);
  socket.on("close", connect_socket); // <- rise from your grave!
  heartbeat();
}

function heartbeat() {
  if (!socket) return;
  if (socket.readyState !== 1) return;
  socket.send("heartbeat");
  setTimeout(heartbeat, 500);
}

connect_socket();
```

I strongly recommend trying to sort out what's happening on the server end, rather than trying to work around it on the client.

Comment: https://github.com/websockets/ws#how-to-detect-and-close-broken-connections

Comment: This is not ping pong. There must be some conventional way to make the client side initiate ping pong, right?

Comment: I appreciate the altered beast ref :)

Comment: @ChrisSchmitz I've been waiting two long years for someone to notice that, now my spirit can finally be free~

Comment: servers generally do not and certainly should not send pings

Comment: servers generally do not and certainly should not send pings: it is for client to decide whether he wants to maintain the connection and server should not force keeping it open on him (this way for example you could drain battery on a mobile device as constant replying to server pings would prevent it from putting radio to sleep)

Comment: There is nothing wrong with a ping/pong initiated from the server side if you want to regularly make sure the client socket is still connected.  The whole point of ping/pong is to detect a broken pipe, not to keep the connection alive.  Battery and radio management are handled by OS and so out of scope here.  However, as for this answer, it is a pretty crude solution that might work in some situations.  500ms is certainly overkill if the disconnect is every 60 seconds.

Comment: @Phil _"The whole point of ping/pong is [...], not to keep the connection alive"_ well, that's not what vast majority of websocket devs expect as you may figure by many similar questions here on SO... As explained in many other posts, intermediate proxies/routers tend to kill idle connections, so keep-alive **is necessary** whether you like it or not and it should **up to client** (in most cases at least) to decide how important the given connection is to him.

Comment: @Phil For example if I have a browser window with a websocket based chat app in the background, I don't want to lose connection while I'm working in the other window. However if I'm on a mobile device and press power to put it into sleep, I usually don't want drain the battery, so the browser should stop pinging (or better ask me what to do).

Comment: @morgwai I was simply disagreeing with your comment that servers should not send pings.  You are clearly confusing ping/pong mechanism with heartbeats and keep-alive.  A good websocket dev will know the difference.

Comment: @Phil you are clearly missing few very basic facts: 1: websocket protocol is always over a reliable lower level protocol, which takes care for *"broken pipes"* and *"making sure the client socket is still connected"*; 2: ping-pong induces connection keep-alive; 3: if you start personal taunts on a public forum it only shows, you don't have any technical arguments left. Generally there are very few examples when it makes sense for the server to do ping-pong, 2 notable ones include: 1: client is unable to do so (majority of browsers unfortunately), 2: RTT discovery (important in games etc)

Comment: or 3. When the server wants to know if a client is still there instead of waiting for TCP disconnect.

https://github.com/websockets/ws#how-to-detect-and-close-broken-connections

This WSS sends a ping every 30 seconds to all known clients to make sure they are still there (broken pipe detection).  Back up your claims rather than getting all tetchy.

Comment: This is objectively a poor way to do it.  The heartbeat should be sent when a message is received instead of using a 500 millisecond interval.  The RFC says that a pong op code frame should be sent when a ping op code frame is received.  Also, re-opening the websocket when it's closed is a huge code smell.

Answer (score 10):

Yes, there are ping/pong frames in websockets.  Here is an example using the `ws` module, where the server is initiating the ping request:

```
const http = require('http');
const ws = require('ws');

const server = http.createServer(function(req_stream_in, res_stream_out) {
  // handle regular HTTP requests here
});
const webSocketServer = new ws.Server({
  path: "/websocket",
  server: server
});

const connected_clients = new Map();

webSocketServer.on('connection', function connection(ws_client_stream) {
  // NOTE: only for demonstration, will cause collisions.  Use a UUID or some other identifier that's actually unique.
  const this_stream_id = Array.from(connected_clients.values()).length;

  // Keep track of the stream, so that we can send all of them messages.
  connected_clients.set(this_stream_id, ws_client_stream);

  // Attach event handler to mark this client as alive when pinged.
  ws_client_stream.is_alive = true;
  ws_client_stream.on('pong', () => { ws_client_stream.is_alive = true; });

  // When the stream is closed, clean up the stream reference.
  ws_client_stream.on('close', function() {
    connected_clients.delete(this_stream_id);
  });
});

setInterval(function ping() {
  Array.from(connected_clients.values()).forEach(function each(client_stream) {
    if (!client_stream.is_alive) { client_stream.terminate(); return; }
    client_stream.is_alive = false;
    client_stream.ping();
  });
}, 1000);
```

Comment: I am not able to access the is_alive property in websocket object?

Comment: Websocket is just another Javascript object so you can add any property on it. Its just the typescript that's not recognising it for that you can either extend the Websocket class or update the typings according to your need.

Comment: This works but it seems that this server side will keep the server very very busy doing this.

Comment: servers generally do not and certainly should not send pings: it is for client to decide whether he wants to maintain the connection and server should not force keeping it open on him (this way for example you could drain battery on a mobile device as constant replying to server pings would prevent it from putting radio to sleep)

Answer (score 7):

Mozilla documents a dedicated convention for ping/pong.

> At any point after the handshake, either the client or the server can
>   choose to send a ping to the other party. When the ping is received,
>   the recipient must send back a pong as soon as possible. You can use
>   this to make sure that the client is still connected, for example.
>
> A ping or pong is just a regular frame, but it's a control frame.
>   Pings have an opcode of 0x9, and pongs have an opcode of 0xA. When you
>   get a ping, send back a pong with the exact same Payload Data as the
>   ping (for pings and pongs, the max payload length is 125). You might
>   also get a pong without ever sending a ping; ignore this if it
>   happens.
>
> If you have gotten more than one ping before you get the chance to
>   send a pong, you only send one pong.

See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API/Writing_WebSocket_servers#Pings_and_Pongs_The_Heartbeat_of_WebSockets

Find more in depth discussion about ping/pong from the browser side here: [Sending websocket ping/pong frame from browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10585355/sending-websocket-ping-pong-frame-from-browser)

More specifically, read the Websocket [RFC 6455](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/rfc6455/?include_text=1) about ping/pong.

Answer (score 1):

In ouni's solution, heartbeat() wasn't kicking in. It works when it's put in an `open` event like this:

```
let socket = null;

function connect_socket() {
  socket = new WebSocket(ws_url);
  socket.on("close", connect_socket); // <- rise from your grave!
  socket.on("open", heartbeat); // heartbeat when the socket is open
}

function heartbeat() {
  if (!socket) return;
  if (socket.readyState !== 1) return;
  socket.send("heartbeat");
  setTimeout(heartbeat, 500);
}

connect_socket();
```

Comment: I think the function heartbeat not will continue calling itself due to returns...