# Is it possible to send a ping opcode using javascript Websocket?

Tags: javascript, websocket

I have a websocket client and I want it to send a ping frame to my WS server.
According to the [RFC 6455](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6455#section-5.2)  a ping frame is represented by opcode %x9 but I don't know if it's even possible to send from a browser.

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: They are automatically sent by the browser/server, you don't have to care about them yourself. There are no functions to force a ping or pong. If you want to, you need to hand-craft them in a WS packet structure. But there is no need to do so in JavaScript. A workaround is to just send an empty packet to the server but I don't see this is necessary either.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sending websocket ping/pong frame from browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10585355/sending-websocket-ping-pong-frame-from-browser)

Comment: Thanks @DanielW., the project I'm currently working on requires to initiate a ping-pong from the client using the standard ping frame

Comment: This is how the `ws` Websocket lib does it: https://github.com/websockets/ws/blob/8a7016dc2fe4d9d63c428c67588d7c1f33a72e5c/lib/sender.js#L209

Comment: Very interesting but can this be done on the client?

Comment: Seems like a duplicate of @DanielW.'s link

Answer (score 1):

Building on-top of the comments in your original post, you can manually send pings via websocket.

The link by Daniel W. of the ws library has a `ping()` method which can be called from a valid websocket client. See an example [here](https://github.com/websockets/ws/#how-to-detect-and-close-broken-connections).

If you have written your own websocket library then you must conform to the standard framing outlined in [RFC6455 The Websocket Protocol](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6455#section-5.2).

You should be able to pack a buffer with the correct header and control opcode and send it over the upgraded HTTP1.1 TCP connection.

Edit:
Further research shows, at the point of writing, the Ping method is not supported via the native [Websocket Client](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSocket/send) and the send method seems to only support payloads and not command messages, which include opcodes for commands such as ping.

An option could be to go with a [WASM based solution](https://rustwasm.github.io/wasm-bindgen/examples/websockets.html) which could make non-XHR or non-fetch based TCP connections, however this comes with a whole different set of challenges.

Comment: This is not what I asked. I wanted to know if it's possible to programmatically initiate a ping frame (0x9) from a browser client. The example you provided does nothing to do with that.

Comment: Apologises if there is a misunderstanding, perhaps you can give further information on what you mean by "programmatically initiate". In the link provided the ws.ping() method sends a ping message from a client, which can be done programmatically. This assumes you are using this library but after reviewing the source code, it looks like they are just packing a buffer and sending with the correct headers over the pre-initiated and upgraded TCP connection.

Comment: thanks. The problem is I don’t think this could run from a browser. If possible, can you add a working sample that will work in the browser?

Comment: I've updated my answer, sadly client-side ping messages don't seem to be supported natively.

Comment: I see, thank you!