# Firefox Websocket security issue

Tags: firefox, websocket

We have a websocket server on port 8080 setup on a Linode box. Chrome and Opera work just fine. Firefox however complains that the operation is insecure.

"The operation is insecure: Code 18"

If I try to create a new WebSocket object in the web console before the page is loaded everything is fine. However, after the page loads something is screwy then I cannot create the object anymore. See the attached screenshot.[image]

I have no idea what operation is insecure or even how to go about diagnosing this.

Comment: I should note that this works fine in development mode connecting to localhost. The Websocket server is exposed directly to the internet on Linode

Comment: Is this a new version of Firefox? They disabled Websockets for a few versions due to security issues.

Comment: @Dreen it is the latest but as you can see on the top of the screenshot I am able to establish a Websoccket connection without issue before loading the page

Answer (score 68, accepted):

I fixed this. The app itself is under SSL but the websocket being accessed is not. Chrome and Opera don't care but Firefox does. According to:

https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=303952

This is known and is not considered a bug. Mozilla's response: wontfix

Solution, put websocket server under SSL and use wss://

Comment: Can you provide info on how to `put websocke server under SSL and use wss://` I'm not sure what exactly you mean to do that.

Comment: @Leeish To use make a secure websocket client, just specify the url with `wss://`. To enable SSL/TLS on the server, you need to refer to the documentation of whatever websocket server you are using. It is possible that TLS is not supported.

Comment: I don't think this bugzilla link is correct, it (currently) points to something about HTTPS certificate mismatches when using SSL tunneling.  The solution is still technically correct, though IMHO the better fix is to turn on `allowInsecureFromHTTPS` so Firefox behaves like other browsers...

Comment: Unfortunately you can't ask your (test) users to change firefox config for that, nor always ask to install a custom certificate if you can't afford one.

Comment: Thank you so much for this answer. Was pulling my hair out and the solution came down to adding a single character on the frontend ('ws://' to 'wss://').

Answer (score 94):

As you point out in another answer, `https://` to `ws://` is disallowed by default on firefox.

Going to firefox's `about:config` and toggling `network.websocket.allowInsecureFromHTTPS` will get rid of the `SecurityError`.

Comment: Yeah this worked! At least there is a workaround for dealing with the nasty restriction of Firefox.

Comment: @FaisalMushtaq: it is not a "nasty restriction" but really a security best practice.

Comment: true, but it makes local development a bit cumbersome. Glad they have the option to configure it!

Answer (score 0):

This is a hunch based off limited info, and I probably should put this into a comment, but I don't have enough reputation points to do that yet.

Looking at your log, it seems as if 24 seconds are passing from the receipt of `[object Websocket]` (time 17:46:36.683) until you get `The connection to ws://.....`(time 17:47:00:952) error message.The long delay leads me to believe that the server could be timing out and closing the websocket connection. Look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9056159/websocket-closing-connection-automatically) for a potential solution.

Comment: If that is the case then why is Chrome and Opera working just fine?

Comment: good point, probably not a server-side timeout unless the server responds differently to different user-agents, which is unlikely...

Comment: actually, it could be possible that the same time-out is occurring, regardless of browser, but that only Firefox is reporting a securityError. Are other browsers re-establishing a websocket? BTW does Linode support websocket? A quick google search provided no conclusive info

Comment: the application is working fine with Chrome and Opera, the websocket server is performing as expected. We have multiple concurrent users with those browsers and no hiccups.

Comment: As far as Linode's websocket support, there is no "support" of Websockets as Linode just provides a VPS. It is up to us to build the server. The websocket server itself is exposed directly to the internet, no proxy inbetween.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem and attempted to fix by changing `network.websocket.allowInsecureFromHTTPS` in `about:config` which did not work.

Ended up finding this post => [Unhandled Rejection (SecurityError): The operation is insecure. On a fresh create-react-app project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58470055/unhandled-rejection-securityerror-the-operation-is-insecure-on-a-fresh-creat)

Changing this in index.js ended up working for me

```
serviceWorker.register();
//serviceWorker.unregister();
```

Answer (score 0):

Open "about:config" url in firefox. Search for allowInsecureFromHTTPS and set it to true

Answer (score 0):

Beside secure ssl context and cross-origin policies, assigning some port can trigger the error as well.

What are valid http ports for Firefox? I don't know precisely, but have to be between `1500` and `64000`, or the console will display:

```
SecurityError: The operation is insecure.
```

And http links will say:

```
This address is restricted

This address uses a network port which is normally used for purposes other than Web browsing.
Firefox has canceled the request for your protection.
```

[image]