# SockJs - error trying to create an unsecure websocket connection from secure page

Tags: websocket, sockjs

Trying to connect to [SockJs server](https://github.com/sockjs/sockjs-node/blob/master/examples/echo/server.js).  I am running the following code from a secure **https** page `https://localhost/index.php`

```
    var sockjs_url = 'http://localhost:9999/echo';
    var sockjs = new SockJS(sockjs_url);

    sockjs.onopen    = function()  {console.log('[*] open' + sockjs.protocol);};
    sockjs.onmessage = function(e) {console.log('[.] message' + e.data);};
    sockjs.onclose   = function()  {console.log('[*] close');};
```

I get `SecurityError: The operation is insecure.` and it falls back to `openxhr-polling`

If I run it from **http** `http://localhost/index.php` websocket connection is established.

Is it not possible to create an unsecure websocket from a secure page?

**UPDATE** This happens in Firefox but in Chrome I'm able to open websocket

**UPDATE 2** Eventually I resolved it by using a https server. [See here.](https://gist.github.com/dev-e-loper/5348625)

**UPDATE 3** Related [Firefox Websocket security issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11768221/firefox-websocket-security-issue)

Answer (score 0):

Some browsers forbid running an insecure WebSocket connection from a secure page, [including FireFox.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API/Writing_WebSocket_client_applications#Security_considerations)