# javascript websock fails with dynamic dns in Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, websocket

The line:

```
ws = new WebSocket(ws_url);
```

fails in firefox with:

```
ws_url="ws://example.duckdns.org:1234/ws/";
```

The websocket does open with the same code in chrome or if the ip address is substituded for the dynamic dns. I need the websocket to open with the duckdns.org dynamic dns in Firefox.

Any ideas on how to get this to work?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11768221/firefox-websocket-security-issue

Comment: What do you mean fails? What does the error message say?

Comment: The console prints out:Firefox can't establish a connection to the server at ws://booyasdrlive.duckdns.org:2008/ws/. openwebrx.js:1641:6, if that's what you mean. As stated above the code works in chrome and if the ip is used.