# Firefox can't establish connection - websocket and heroku

Tags: security, firefox, heroku, websocket, actioncable

I have problem with websocket connection on heroku.

Not sure where is the problem, because on other browsers it works.
A similar issue was here:

[Firefox Websocket security issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11768221/firefox-websocket-security-issue)

If I understand correctly:

Something related to Heroku and backend is missing regards to security. Only Firefox care about this issue, other browsers not. Probably I can somehow ignore this error on firefox and allow a connection.

Below is the screenshot `The connection used to fetch this resource was not secure` - what exactly does it mean and how debug what and where is missing here?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After research, the reason for it was proxy on Firefox.

If someone would have a similar issue, please do:

1. Open the Firefox
2. Go to about:preferences
3. Open Network Settings
4. Configure Proxy Access to the Internet and be sure there is "No proxy"

Comment: Hi, could you explain the underlying reason for doing this? Thanks!