# HERE geocoder-autocomplete with ReactJS suddenly returning Network Error on Firefox

Tags: reactjs, axios, here-api, here-autocomplete

I've implemented the solution from the [HERE tutorial](http://ttps://developer.here.com/blog/street-address-validation-with-reactjs-and-here-geocoder-autocomplete) and it worked well on firefox and chrome. However, few weeks ago it stopped working on **Firefox** and started returning `Network Error`. The request doesn't even show on my network log.

I've tested the [API EndPoint](https://developer.here.com/documentation/geocoder-autocomplete/topics/quick-start-get-suggestions.html) w/ my credentials and it worked. It also worked on Google Chrome.

I've tried to hardcode the credential and also via `.env` and neither approach worked on firefox

My code:

```
try {
  const address = await axios.get(`https://autocomplete.geocoder.api.here.com/6.2/suggest.json`,{
    params: {
      app_id: APP_ID_HERE,
      app_code: APP_CODE_HERE,
      query,
      maxresults: 1,
      country: 'AUS',
      state: 'Western Australia'
    }
  });    
  console.log('address:',address);
} catch (error) {
  console.log('address-error:',error);
}
```

Dependencies:

```
"dependencies": {
  "axios": "^0.19.0",
  "react": "^16.8.6",
}
```

Have HERE changed anything towards this API?

I've also raised the issue with Axios -> https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/2388

Thanks

Comment: There is no change w.r.t to API, it would be helpful if the response could be shared that you are received.. any response code or error

Comment: @HEREDeveloperSupport any updates on this? thanks

Comment: This indicates an authentication error: 401 -  Validation of app_id/app_code pair failed. Either app_code does not match the app_id or the app_id is not entitled to use the Geocoder Autocomplete API.

Comment: @HEREDeveloperSupport, It does not make any sense because it works on Chrome but not on Firefox!!!

Comment: @HEREDeveloper, I found the issue: Firefox is blocking some assets, atm a fresh react-app gives this error: `Unhandled Rejection (SecurityError): The operation is insecure.` but it runs correctly on a `private window` and the API also works on it. But I am not sure how to resolve it....

Answer (score 0):

This is more related to firefox web-socket security issue, for resolution please refer [Firefox Websocket security issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11768221/firefox-websocket-security-issue/12042843#12042843) and do let us know if you still have issues with this.

The app itself is under SSL but the websocket being accessed is not. Chrome and Opera don't care but Firefox does. According to:

https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=303952

This is known and is not considered a bug. Mozilla's response: wontfix

```
Solution, put websocket server under SSL and use wss://
```