# Unhandled Rejection (SecurityError): The operation is insecure. On a fresh create-react-app project

Tags: reactjs, firefox

I created a new project with create-react-app then ran npm start then this showed up.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/GzXmh.jpg

Using FF 69.0.3

Comment: I have the same error, created an issue in create-react-app repo https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/8047

Comment: literally none of these answers fixed it for me

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This problem seems to only happen in Firefox. Edge worked fine.

After creating the project, in `index.js` change:

```
serviceWorker.register();
//serviceWorker.unregister();
```

Still trying to figure whose fault this is, but this should get you going.

Comment: this registers the serviceworker, which comes with a bunch of caveats https://create-react-app.dev/docs/making-a-progressive-web-app/#why-opt-in

Comment: @tobbe: Indeed, but do you have an answer for why it happens and a better way to fix it?

Answer (score 8):

Another solution found in the [link](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/16076#issuecomment-699430272) in the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64604133/11138267) by Niraj Niroula:

If you want to keep the **Delete cookies and site data when Firefox is closed** option enabled, click on the <kbd>Manage Exceptions</kbd> button and add localhost (with the protocol and port) to the exceptions list:

[image: cookie and site data deletion exceptions]

Answer (score 5):

Seems that the issue exists only in Firefox. Anyone still bugged by this bug can try disabling **Delete cookies and site data when Firefox is closed** option in **Privacy and Security settings**.
[image]
Or try wrapping the `navigator.serviceWorker` usages inside a try/catch. In my case

```
  if ("serviceWorker" in navigator) {
    navigator.serviceWorker.ready
      .then(registration => {
        registration.unregister();
      })
      .catch(error => console.log("ServiceWorker Warning: ", error));
  }
```

[For related discussion and more info](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/16076)

Comment: Adding the `.catch(error => console.log("ServiceWorker Warning: ", error));` line fixed it for me. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

A lot of answers here do actually solve the issue but the simplest way I have found is to add npm package [serve](https://www.npmjs.com/package/serve) to your dependencies.

`yarn add serve` or `npm i serve`

and then replace your start script with the following:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "serve -s build",
}
```

This is actually straight out of the create-react-app [docs](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment)

Answer (score 3):

I had this error occur as well. Was able to clear it up by deleting the create-react-app serviceWorker.js file

Answer (score -1):

For me, it was a malformed URL in the call to the `route()` function in PreactJS.

I basically added a slash too much when integrating the `process.env.PUBLIC_PATH` variable into my links like so:

```js
export function Example(props: {}) {
  const callback = useCallback((e: JSX.TargetedEvent<HTMLButtonElement>) => {
    route(`${process.env.PUBLIC_PATH}/my/path`)
//                                   ^
//                                   That slash is too much
  }, [])
  return <button onClick={callback}>Click me</button>
}
```

After clicking the button, the URL looked something like this in my Chrome location bar:

```
https://localhost/my-app//my/path
                        ^^
                        Here is the forbidden double slash
```

Interestingly, only Firefox reported this to me, while Chrome happily rendered the page and ignored the double slash.

The solution was simply to remove the unnecessary slash, since `env.process.PUBLIC_PATH` always needs to end with a slash:

```js
route(`${process.env.PUBLIC_PATH}my/path`)
//                              ^^
//                              No extra slash fixed it!
```