# WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 404

Tags: javascript, websocket, wildfly-8

Am writing my first websocket program and am getting **"WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 404", error while loading the webpage.**

I am using JDK 1.7 and jboss 8 (wildfly8.0).

Could anyone please assist?

```
window.onload = init;
var socket = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:8080/WebsocketHome/actions"); 
socket.onmessage = onMessage;
```

and head in html

```
<head> 
 <title></title>
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
 <script src="websocket.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"> 
</head>
```

Comment: can you shows us how you created the web socket first? 404 usually that your url is cannot be found. and I think rather than posing your code in comment, it will be great if you just edit your post.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Thank you guys for your suggestion, I found the answer.

The code I copied is from http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/java/HomeWebsocket/WebsocketHome.html site.

The problem was the url as mentioned in the js file and the project name they are proposing is WebsocketHome. I had changed the project name to Websocket thus my url should be ws://localhost:8080/Websocket/actions.

Thanks for your support.

Answer (score 3):

Actually, the problem here is case-sensitivity in the URLs. You did not need to change the project name. Just changing the Websocket URL in JavaScript file to

```
ws://localhost:8080/WebSocketHome/actions
```

(with capital S, as in the project name) would have solved the problem. In your case, changing both of them removed the case inconsistency, so it worked.

Answer (score 0):

It's because of the issue of /info=34424 - with 404 error - that I had to abandon using the xml approach suggested at [other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22481357/stomp-over-socket-using-sockjs-cant-connect-with-spring-4-websocket) places. I have Spring 4.2 in my project and many SockJS Stomp implementations usually work well with Spring Boot implementations. [This implementation from Baeldung](https://www.baeldung.com/websockets-spring) worked(for me without changing from Spring 4.2 to 5). After Using the dependencies mentioned in his blog, it still gave me ClassNotFoundError. I added the below dependency to fix it.

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```

Baeldung's implementation curiously does not make any such calls

```
flow/websocket/add/info?t=1540813753999
```

What it does (on send and receive) is below. I am only pasting it in case people well-versed with these libraries can further add insights on this forum.

```
 >>> SEND
destination:/app/chat
content-length:38

{"from":"nicholas","text":"try again"}

<<< MESSAGE
destination:/topic/messages
content-type:application/json;charset=UTF-8
subscription:sub-0
message-id:m3p096zk-11
content-length:53

{"from":"nicholas","text":"try again","time":"13:46"}
```

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you are trying to contact the websocket with a normal browser.
That is not allowed and gives a 404 error. You need to use a script or curl to address websockets.