# Does akka actors will able to use websocket session ? does websocket connection closes before actors start using?

Tags: java, websocket, akka

I am having three actors,able to send data to client from the first actor but some how session is closing for second,third actors.I want what is causing the closing of session,I have tried onClose(..) method but debug pointer is not coming to onClose(..) method.Can any one tell how to intercept the session closing ?

```
public class ScheduleMgmtWebSocket extends BaseWebSocket {
    @OnMessage
    public void onMessage(String message, Session session) {
    actor1.tell(session);
    actor2.tell(session);
}
```

here when control comes out of onMessage does session closes i.e whole web socket instance closes ?when instance closes actors no more can send data to clients ? Can any expert clarify me please

Comment: what about onError()? see what's happening there.

Comment: possible duplicate of [websocket closing connection automatically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9056159/websocket-closing-connection-automatically)

Comment: @bayou.io Tried onError().control is not going there also

Comment: which websocket library are you using?

Comment: weblogic is the implementation provider.

Comment: This question is tagged akka, how is it related to akka?