# Debugging websocket failures behind corporate proxy/firewall

Tags: node.js, websocket

I have read in numerous places that in theory an ssl/443 websocket connection has a high percentage success rate when the client is behind corporate proxy/firewalls.  This topic also touches on the issue:  [Websockets behind enterprises proxies](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9017113).

Our setup is node.js with websocket-node server side, passing binary data to Chrome 15+ client.  No issues with performance as it is blazing fast.  I do however have failed connections within corporations, in one example I know they are using an explicit proxy, connecting to that proxy server on port 8080.

The first question is two part:  a) what mechanisms can I use to debug the issue to know what is blocking the upgrade, and b) for those with experience what is most likely the culprit?

Secondly, what performance hit will I take if I fall back to flash (i.e. websocket-js)?

Many thanks in advance.

**UPDATE:**  It is now clear that the upgrade handshake request is never being seen by the websocket server, so it is being blocked on the client side before the request ever gets out.

Comment: Note that there are transparent Web proxies deployed on corporate networks which even will _unwrap_ SSL (they effectively act as man-in-the-middle).If they don't like your cert or don't like WS Upgrade header, they can deny. Those would have been my main concern .. and yep, I am also concerned. Even WSS on 443 with valid cert will not pass everywhere ..

Comment: @oberstet:  with such proxies are there rules that can be applied to allow certain connections?  In general, we will have support to get necessary passage permissions, the issue is knowing how to debug the problem.  Any insights into debugging is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I know you are looking for method to debug this stuff. Its tricky I guess, and I can't provide an answer.

One thing related to WSS. You will want to make sure that your WSS endpoint uses a cert which can be verified / is accepted by the intermediary (your CA cert needs to be on that proxy).

Comment: From the browser side, a WS/WSS connection is treated as a "subresource". That means you might not even get a "Accept/Deny" dialog. Nor a _specific_ (TLS failed) JS error. With a normal HTML page (not a subresource), the browser may render such a dialog, and/or the proxy (normally transparent) may show up: TLS denied, target cert disallowed.

Comment: About the cert...that is a good point.  If the node.js https server and wss are the same endpoint then we will see in the browser whether it has been verified by simply clicking on the "lock".  In this case our certificate says that it has been verified, however it has a warning sign saying that it "failed to check if it has been revoked".  I should also mention that we are using the free StartCom  class 1 cert.